# No module named "pyfingerprint"

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, fingerprint

I followed a guide about how to operate a fingerprint sensor using python. It works fine when using the terminal to execute the example files. But whenever I try to use it with a *Thorny or Python IDLE*. It keeps saying:

```
from pyfingerprint.pyfingerprint import PyFingerprint
ImportError: No module named 'pyfingerprint'
```

I would appreciate it so much if anyone can help me run those examples on a python idle.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct code you ran? The "f" in "From" should not be capitalized.

Comment: python 3 or 2 .... choose one - what are you using?

Comment: @JordanSinger Sorry, that was a typo. It is indeed 'f' and not 'F'

Comment: @PatrickArtner Python 3 sir.

Comment: you might need to use pip3 possibly

Comment: delete the question. Doesn't help anyone if it's your typo mistake.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the exact version( including minor version) of Python you're running in the command line .
2. In Geany (that's what I use) under menu Build>Set Build Commands ,  in the Compile and Execute fields set to that Python version eg python3.5 . Then you can be sure command line and IDE are compiling/executing against the same version.